# java Lang UnsupportedClassVersion Error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error when I am building my project . How do I correct this ?

[image]

Supported Version Details

[image]

JAVA SDK

[image]

Comment: Followed same steps but still getting issue

Comment: Make sure to delete your `bin/obj` folders in your project as it most likely has a cached `JDK` path in the `sdk.cache` file. Please post your full diagnostic build output if that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas. After Deleting Bin/Obj error has gone. Now I am getting different error, As below                                                                     1>Please select a valid device before running the application.
1>------ Deploy started: Project: App2.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Error: Cancelled
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I will add an answer. Please post another question for your other error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete your `bin/obj` folders in your project as it most likely has a cached `JDK` path in the `sdk.cache` file.